# How to insert a permanent cable into a receptacle to add a second receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, garage

I'd like to set up a new receptacle 12 ft away from an existing (120V/60Hz/15A) receptacle in a garage.

There are two options. The connection will go either behind or in front of the existing drywall.

Going behind the drywall means that to pass the [fish tape](https://www.homedepot.com/s/fish%2520tape)
the electrician would leave me with several large holes, which I would subsequently need to patch up.

That's why I'd rather keep the cable outside—resting on the 2-ft high concrete in the garage—and insert the cable into the two receptacles on both ends. If the cable remains outside, the job is simple enough I can do it myself.

But I'm unclear how the cable should enter the receptacle in a clean way. How to insert a permanent cable into a receptacle to add a second receptacle?

[image: receptacle in dry wall above concrete in garage]

##### Update following Triplefault's answer

One obvious solution is to replace the existing receptacle with a protruding receptacle (the picture shown below is from
[here](https://www.thespruce.com/adding-an-outdoor-outlet-by-tapping-into-an-existing-circuit-1152805)),
but that would be rather ugly. Is there a cleaner solution?

[image: protruding receptacle]

Comment: You have smooth walls, which means patching those holes would be fairly easy. I strongly urge you to reconsider a hacky surface strategy which will almost be _more_ work (surface-mount stuff is putzy). If your sparky needs _large_ holes, get a new sparky.

Comment: @isherwood But whether a pro patches the holes or I do it myself, the trace of the holes will be visible; is that right? In any case, I asked a separate question, to at least understand how a cable is passed behind a drywall.

Comment: Can you remove the faceplate and (after turning off the breaker) pull out the receptacle? Don't disconnect any wires. Just want to see what type of box this is, as that may affect the options.

Comment: Not if you do it _right_.

Comment: Surface conduit isn’t hacky, it’s great for basements and garages. Who cares if it’s visible there? It means you can add or replace wires any time without ripping open the wall *again* as you’d have to do with in-wall cables.

Comment: @nobody Cool. Can you add an answer briefly saying how to connect to the receptacle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the drywall is a lot less work.

Instead of cutting holes in the drywall, cut a rectangle out of the drywall for the full length from outlet to outlet. If you cut it nearly (use a reciprocating tool rather than a drywall saw for a very thin cut) you can simply put it right back afterward. Use a magnet to find the existing screws and avoid them, or unscrew them.

To answer your question about running it on the surface: It's not legal to put Romex on a wall like that, because it can be damaged too easily. I'm not really sure what you mean by "2ft high concrete" because I don't see anything like that in your photo. But it sounds like you want to run the Romex on the concrete wall of your garage 2ft above the ground, which is easily exposed to damage, and against code.

So your choices are armored wire, conduit, or a raceway. With conduit or armored wire the outlets are no longer recessed in the wall, the are placed on the wall.

With a raceway you get a special box that has a small opening in the top or side for the raceway. Like this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Legrand-NMW-3-Piece-White-Raceway-Switch-Box-Kit/3132549 look at the photos linked with the product to see how the whole system works.

Personally I would remove the drywall, then reinstall it after.

Comment: Looks like below the "baseboard" is concrete or concrete block.

Answer (score 2):

Look for surface-mount wiring channels or raceways. These channels will have boxes that mount over the receptacle box, projecting out of the wall a small amount. The receptacle and plate go in the extension box, as well as a wire channel to carry the new wires to the next box, which would be a standalone surface-mount box, for another receptacle and plate.

Comment: I understand that the cable should ideally be hidden inside a channel (but this is cosmetic rather than functional). I also understand that the cable will have a couple of 90-degree turns (which will be tricky to conceal using the straight channels). What I'm unclear about is how the cable will _enter_ the receptacle. Are you suggesting that there is a special receptacle that protrudes a little, and that has space to insert the wiring?

Comment: For a less industrial look, https://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-Non-Metallic-PVC-Raceway-15-Amp-Duplex-Receptacle-Box-Kit-with-Faceplate-and-Outlet-White-NMW2-D/100544174

Comment: @Sam7919 It's not cosmetic, it's a code requirement. You can not have exposed wire on a wall. See my reply for a link to the kind of box you are asking about.